# Help identifying a part

Tags: gears, gear-stick

I was driving home today and suddenly found that I could only select 3rd gear. When inspecting the linkages inside the gear stick housing I realized that something on the the end of the rod must have sheered off  stopping it manipulating the linkages inside. In fact they were falling off the end of the rod attached to the ball joint on the base of the gear stick. In the process of getting it home I snapped the inside plastic mech part(the cable ties were my addition to get it home and likely contributed to the snapped part). My question is what part/set am I looking for when buying a replacement. I have searched with multiple gear related terms and cannot find anything suitable. [image: picture of mechanism]

Thanks for the awnsers to date. The diagram was useful. I has disassembled the unit and these [image: these] are the parts I'm after.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It would really help us if you could give us the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question. Different manufacturers call parts different things. We *might* even be able to get you a part number.

Answer (score 1):

With my Toyota Aygo we had sort of the same Problem. 
You could only order 2 parts: The actual gear leaver assembly and the shift cables. You should identify what´s actually the problem: 
Is the lever damaged, so the link/cable does not attach, or is the connecor on the link damaged/missing a clip?

Try typing into google your make and model and "shift exploded view" and you´ll probably find something like this, to see what parts are available, (sometimes with OEM parts-numbers)
[image: Exploded view of the shift lever component on models with a manual transmission-Mazda3]

(Example: Mazda 3 manual transmission)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you could do is to search for a schematic diagram of your transmission shifter assembly to correctly identify the part that you are needing. this would save you the cost of buying a set and just use a part of it.

Comment: Or go to the car dealership and ask them. It will be a dealer only part, that or salvage yard.

Comment: a little research can do a long way. props to the asker for actually wanting to research about what part he really needs. or.. best case is that the bushings are available piece by piece for his car.

Comment: If it is a dealer only part, research will be fruitless unless you have access to a car manufacturers software to look up the part.

Comment: @Moab - How would they know it's a "dealer only part" without researching it first? Dealership is always the last resort for research for me, because I would have to travel there to make sure they are looking at the part I'm searching for ... looking for it on the internet is a logical first step.

Comment: I agree with Paulster2: some vehicles' parts diagrams and catalogs are available to the public online. Searching eBay can also yield part numbers. In this case, we're still hobbled because the OP hasn't identified the make, model, and year of the vehicle in question.